# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre poner una pregunta "en espera" o "cerrada"?

Tags: discusión

He visto que una pregunta (¿mala?) puede ser ***cerrada*** o ser puesta ***en espera***, ¿cuál es la diferencia si al editar la pregunta ambas pueden regresar a la vida?

Ambas estatus tienen el mismo mensaje descriptivo:

> Edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico, con el
>   suficiente nivel de detalle para permitir identificar una respuesta
>   adecuada. Evita preguntar varias cosas distintas a la vez. Visita la
>   página Cómo preguntar para obtener ayuda sobre cómo aclarar esta
>   pregunta.

Comment: De [What is a “closed” or “on hold” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10583/209901) Básicamente, que está "en espera" durante los cinco primeros días después de cerrarse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las preguntas pueden tener uno de varios estados. En [¿Qué significa pregunta si una pregunta está "cerrada" o "en espera"?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) se mencionan los dos mencionados en la pregunta, pero hay otros posibles estados:

```
     +--------------+--------------+--------------+
     |              |              |              |
     |      |--> en espera ---> cerrada -->|      |
     |      |                              |      |
     V      |----------------------------->|      |
 abierta -->|                              |--> borrada 
            |--------> protegida --------->|
            |                              |
            |----> bloqueada (locked) ---->|
```

Ciertas preguntas pueden ser [protegidas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions) por un miembro con reputación de 3,500 o mas con la finalidad de evitar respuestas de usuarios anónimos o muy recientes.

De [locked-questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/locked-questions/info)

> Locking a question prevents answering, editing, commenting, voting, closing, and reopening. Answers must be locked separately and may still be voted upon. Only diamond moderators may lock posts.

Traducción propuesta

> Bloquear una pregunta previene respuestas, ediciones, comentarios, votos, cierre y reapertura. Las respuesta deben ser bloqueadas por separado y podrían continuar siendo votadas. Sólo los moderadores diamantados pueden bloquear publicaciones.

Además, de acuerdo a [Enable automatic deletion of old, unanswered zero-score questions after a year?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78048/289691), las preguntas bloqueadas no son borradas por el algoritmo de eliminación de preguntas antiguas/abandonadas/no-amadas

Comment: ¿En lugar de *bloqueada* no sería *protegida*?

Comment: Pues es cuestión de preferencias de traducción ¿has visto cómo se ha traducido en otras publicaciones en SOes?

Comment: La parte del bloqueo de preguntas no la había visto, y me refiero al [privilegio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions) de proteger preguntas.

Comment: Pues protegida es otro estado

Comment: He añadido la transición de (borrada, cerrada o en espera) a Abierta. De protegida o bloqueada a abierta imagino que también es posible; pero debe ser mucho menos habitual.

Comment: @Ruben una pregunta, ¿de un estado *protegido*  puede pasar a *en espera*? Sí es así, entonces habría que hacer algunos ajustes al flujo :)

Comment: Según entiendo una pregunta puedes estar en estado *protegido* y *en espera* al mismo tiempo. En cuanto a los ajustes al diagrama, la intención es que sea un diagrama ilustrativo (no exhaustivo) :)