# A que se debe el tag de "cerrada"

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, cierre-de-preguntas

He visto [en un post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/90364/vista-proporcional-a-diagrama-de-punto-leaflet-openlayers)  que han puesto el tag al lado de "[cerrada]" , me parece absurdo , porque si el que pone el autor de la pregunta , le da al stick si ya cumple sus expectativas , pero poner eso , es redundante.
No se si es algo que se aplica en global en stackoverflow o simplemente es algo que nosotros ponemos para diferenciarnos.

La pregunta simplemente es eso ¿Es alguna normativa nueva que se aplica?

Comment: Creo que es automático. [cerrada] y [en espera] los pone el sistema si la publicación tiene ese estado. No es nuevo, siempre funciona así. Esta guía te puede ayudar a comprender que pasa: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions

Comment: No me queda clara tu duda, CodeNoob: ¿te refieres a que ponga "openlayers" al final del título o a que aparezca "[cerrada]"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Respuesta corta

Favor de leer [¿Qué significa si una pregunta "cerrada" o "en espera"?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)

## Explicación

En los títulos pueden aparecer las siguientes etiquetas de estado

- [cerrada]
- [en espera]
- [duplicada]
- [bloqueada]
- [migrada]

Estas etiquetas del sistema se asignan luego que las preguntas en cuestión han sido puestas en el estado correspondiente ya sea por votación de los miembros con el privilegio correspondiente o bien directamente por un miembro con medalla dorada en una de las etiquetas creadas por la comunidad o por un moderador de la comunidad.

## Referencias

### Artículos de ayuda relacionados

- [¿Qué son las etiquetas, y cómo debo usarlas?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

### Otras preguntas en Meta

- [¿Cuál es la diferencia entre poner una pregunta "en espera" o "cerrada"?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1702/65)

### Preguntas del FAQ

- [¿Qué es una publicación bloqueada?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1994/65)